# javascript pop window replace original html source

Tags: javascript

I have added following java script code to create a pop window:

```
document.write('<center>');

    document.write('<div id="productComapreBox" style="border:0px solid #0066FF ; padding:5px; font-size:150%; text-align:center; display:none; width:820px; height:600px;">');
        document.write('<input type="image" src="images/close.png" width="30" height="30" alt="X" onClick="'+eval(Popup.hide("productComapreBox"))+'" style="cursor:pointer; float:right; z-index:20;">');
        document.write('<div style="z-index:20;">');

            document.write('<iframe width="800px" height="600px" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" src="<?php echo $domainName; ?>productComaprePop.php?productComapreIds='+productId+'"></iframe>');

        document.write('</div>');
    document.write('</div>');

document.write('</center>');
```

It is opening pop window as I want but it replace original html source. how to prevent this.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: You may want to read about the `appenChild()`method. Note that HTML generation from javascript should be avoided when possible, exactly like inline styles, and iFrames should be used only when you can't do else.

Comment: Where have you find this `document.write()` function? It's not supposed to be used when creating content to an existing page, rather it's purposed to create whole new documents.

Comment: `document.write` will replace the content. Don't use it. Use dynamic DOM manipulation instead. [HTMLElement.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

Comment: I don't see any code that creates a popup window.  This is also quite an antiquated style of JS/HTML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using document.write, you can use this code-

HTML-

```
<div id="container" style="display: none;">
<center>
<div id="productComapreBox" style="border:0px solid #0066FF ; padding:5px; font-size:150%; text-align:center; display:none; width:820px; height:600px;">
<input type="image" src="images/close.png" width="30" height="30" alt="X" onClick="'+eval(Popup.hide("productComapreBox"))+'" style="cursor:pointer; float:right; z-index:20;">
<div style="z-index:20;">
<iframe id="frame" width="800px" height="600px" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</center>
</div>
```

Javascript-

```
function unhide(){
var fullurl = "<?php echo $domainName; ?>productComaprePop.php?productComapreIds='" + productId + "'";
document.getElementById('frame').scr=fullurl;
document.getElementById('container').style.display="block";
}
```

So you can display this content simply by calling `unhide()` without disturbing the rest of your code.

Comment: problem is that iframe url is dynamic based on product selected for comparison. see

 src="<?php echo $domainName; ?>productComaprePop.php?productComapreIds='+productId+'"

Comment: you can assign the value of the complete url to a variable in php like this - `$fullurl = $domainName.'productComaprePop.php?productComapreIds='.+productId+;`. Then just use this - `src = "<?php echo fullurl; ?>"` I have updated this in my answer also.

Comment: but problem is that productId in full url is not know when in php. I can get that only via javascript when user select checkbox for comparing products. That is you can in my code has have javascript '+productId+'"

Comment: I have updated my answer according to what you want. I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks buddy. its done. One small correction instead of document.getElementById('frame').scr=fullurl; it will be 'src'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to append your new elements, not overwrite what you currently have.

eg.

```
var location = document.getElementById('#somElement');
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var div = document.createElement('DIV');
var secondDiv = document.createElement('DIV');

div.appendChild(secondDiv);
fragment.appendChild(div);
location.appendChild(fragment);
```